# Using pfccomp or pint to run Pascal-FC programs

Tags: pascal-fc

I'm using the Pascal FC implementation for Windows Vista found on http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/burns/pf.html

I'm trying to run the [dining philophers problem found on the link](http://www-users.cs.york.ac.uk/burns/pf.html) but I don't get how to make the compiler work.

[Screenshot](http://img28.imageshack.us/img28/383/pfccomp.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In the screen shot, the program appears to be waiting for you to enter the name of the file to use for the compiler output. Enter a file name.

Better yet, use the *pfc.bat* command and let it choose the output names for you. The batch file will also run the program automatically after it has been compiled. At the command prompt, run the command like this:

```
C:\pascalfc-vista> pfc philchan.pas
```